# Properly scope functions and methods

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, security

I wanted to ask a question about securing my web site.  I have an ASP.net site, using VB.  I have decided on a 3 tiered approach.  So, one project, with three applications.  The first application is the website, the second is a class library for business logic, and the last is a class library for database interactions.

My question is on how do I protect functions/subs in my various tiers, from be accessed and used outside of the project?  I can't make the functions/subs Private, Protected, or Friends as each library is in its own project.  But, I want to make sure other entities, outside of the project, can access resources.  Here is an example layout of my project:

> MySolution
>
> ```
>  MyWebSite - Has references to MyBusinessLayer and MyDataLayer class libraries
>
>  MyBusinessLayer - Has a reference to MyDataLayer
>
>  MyDataLayer - has no References
> ```

Example code would be:

**MyWebsite load:**

```
Public DATA_PROXY As New MyDataLayer
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    dim someData as new Users = DATA_PROXY.getSomeData()
    'do stuff with data
end Sub
```

**MyBusinessLayer**

```
Public Function getSomeData() As Users
      Dim conn As New myBussinessLayer
      Dim dr As SqlDataReader
      conn.Connect()
      dr = conn.getSomeDataFromDB()
      '...more code for logic done here and returns an object      
end function
```

**MyDataLayer**

```
 Public Function getSomeDataFromDB() As SqlDataReader
       Dim dr As SqlDataReader
      '... do stuff to get data from database 
       return dr
 end function
```

So, you can see everything is Public.  Is this a bad pattern to use?  Can other, outside entities, access these DLLs once they are deployed?  What are some security concerns I should have?  Also, are there any issues with using this pattern of development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial answer.

You have the beginnings of going down the right path. The use of layers is a concept to hide (or encapsulate) various functions from those who do not need to know the implementation. But your implementation of the layers will give you grief. I will use your three layers. I will also use the term "function" liberally where I mean either function or sub-routine depending on the context.

The use of (server-side) ASP helps, because the output is a rendered page, not an exposed series of function calls or scripts (always one of my beefs with client-side JavaScript).

MyWebsite should have the public facing code. This can be the functions that render information onto the page, or validate and accept input from the users. Tightly manage the function calls (arguments/parameters) so that you only get inputs that you expect.

With MyBusinessLayer and MyDataLayer, create some interface/adapter functions that do nothing else except validate inputs (the function arguments/parameters), call the working functions, and then validate the outputs (so that website exposing code or Cross-scripting does not occur). All the other functions that do the work (and thus expose details of the actual database etc) can be Private or Friend. The tighter you can make it, the easier it is to secure.

These extra functions initially seem like more work - but aid in maintenance at a later stage. If your database details change, you can update the Private working code, but if it give the same type of output then your higher level interfaces do not change and all the layers above do not change. From a security perspective, you have now minimised the work to check for any security issues due to code change.

Going back to your original post:

- *Is this a bad pattern to use?* The pattern itself is not bad - as I have noted above it is the implementation of that pattern that is important.
- *Can other, outside entities, access these DLLs once they are
  deployed?*  If they are Public - yes.
- *What are some security concerns I should have?* If people can bypass your interface functions (because your working code is also public), they can bypass your validations. Sure, you can put validations in your working code, but from experience this results in much duplication, mistakes and much harder to maintain. This is a good question though - design with security in mind because it is much harder to add security later. So - you minimise what the others can see and access.
- *Also, are there any issues with using this pattern of development?* I have used this pattern of development myself (User interface, business logic, data adapters) and it works. It is more work initially and, if you are like me (code - run - code - work out what I am doing - design a bit - code - run etc), sometimes seems to be a lot of rework. But, from my experience, this short-term pain is definitely worth the long-term gain.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  I have to have this reviewed by our CIO shop and want to make sure I take as much into consideration as possible!

Comment: thanks for your response.  so, just to be clear, though, there's no direct way to scope functions in Data Layer to only be accessed by the Business Layer?  So, it would make sense to do my security check (checking authentication and authorization) at the lowest level (i.e Data Layer)?

Comment: @Jason: If the code is in separate projects then I can't see a way to absolutely tie it down. But the exposed interfaces - your own APIs - help make it **safe** code. I can't speak to authorisations and authentications because there are a range of local business policies that have to be considered - but I think you would need that at all layers. Authenticating and authorising users/applications/systems is another consideration on too of the information [format/type] validation.

Comment: @Jason: but the API method I have described will make inserting authentication and authorisation elements easier.

Comment: thanks for the input and assistance.  It's good to know I'm on the right path.